# How to JsDoc a "mixed" type?

Tags: parameters, mixed, jsdoc

Simple question, how do I document that "Mixed-type"? I know I could just list all possible types like `{null|undefined|String|Number|Object}` and end up finding myself missing one and making it overly complex. I tried using the Mixed keyword, but it popups errors in many IDEs such as WebStorm.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I found the way to do it:

```
/**
 * @param {*} foo
 */
function bar(foo) {}
```

Comment: Where did you find that? My search results can only verify that this will work for the [Closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types). Is it 'official' JSDoc syntax?

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen Take a look at *The ALL type* the almost last: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler?hl=de#types

Comment: @yckart Like I said before; [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) != [Closure compiler](http://developers.google.com/closure).

Comment: But gc is one of the major jsdoc-definers ;) Here's a good ressource about jsdoc and its *background*: http://wiki.servoy.com/display/public/DOCS/Annotating+JavaScript+using+JSDoc;jsessionid=5DD1388ED3DA0D59FC43114AC9492E0A#AnnotatingJavaScriptusingJSDoc-TypeExpressions

Comment: I created an [issue for adding this type](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/468) in the JSDoc 3 issue tracker.

Comment: This is in jsdoc documentation now:
http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#multiple-types-and-repeatable-parameters

Answer (score 3):

Use **{}**

There is an example from http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html:

> An object called 'myObj' with properties 'a' (a number), 'b' (a
>   string) **and 'c' (any type)**.
>
> ```
> {{a: number, b: string, c}} myObj
> // or:
> {Object} myObj
> {number} myObj.a
> {string} myObj.b
> {} myObj.c
> ```

Answer (score 3):

In JSDoc, you can describe values in different ways. For example, using the following tags `@type`, `@param`, `@return`.
You can specify optional values using the "?". Here is an example

```
    /**
     * Returns string or null
     *
     * @param {?string} nullableStringArgument
     *
     * @return {?string}
     */
    function returnNullableString (nullableStringArgument = null) {
        /** @type {?string} */
        const nullableString = [null, 'string'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];

        return nullableString;
    }
```