# How to specify an array of objects as a parameter or return value in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

In JSDoc, the best documentation I can find shows to use the following if you have an array of a specific type (such as an array of strings) as:

```
/**
 * @param {Array.<string>} myStrings All my awesome strings
 */
 function blah(myStrings){
     //stuff here...
 }
```

How would you replace the below question marks specify an array of objects?

```
/**
 * @param {???????} myObjects All of my equally awesome objects
 */
 function blah(myObjects){
     //stuff here...
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Document collection (array of type) return value and parameter in JSDoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498975/document-collection-array-of-type-return-value-and-parameter-in-jsdoc)

Answer (score 321, accepted):

You should be more specific what you mean by JSDoc - this is a generic term covering pretty much all the JavaDoc-style documentation tools for JavaScript.

The syntax you used for array of strings looks like the one supported by [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types).

Using this, an array of Objects would be:

```
/**
 * @param {Array.<Object>} myObjects
 */
```

Or just an array of anything - this should work with pretty much all doc tools:

```
/**
 * @param {Array} myArray
 */
```

[jsdoc-toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagParam), [JSDoc 3](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html), and [JSDuck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/wiki/Type-Definitions) support the following syntax to denote an array of objects:

```
/**
 * @param {Object[]} myArray
 */
```

---

### EDIT

In case you know the keys and the variable type of the values you can also do:

```
/**
 * @param {Array.<{myNumber: Number, myString: String, myArray: Array}>} myObjects
 */
```

or

```
/**
 * @param {{myNumber: Number, myString: String, myArray: Array}[]} myObjects
 */
```

Comment: The . notation is now deprecated and its support should be dropped later. Current correct version is `{Array<Object>}`. Just to keep this  post up to date.

Comment: With JSDoc 3, how would you doc an array of String arrays?  In the old syntax I might do something like `Array.<string[]>`

Comment: @Kenny806 Deprecated? A reference document please?

Comment: @Wilt: the [JSDoc documentation is contradictory](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1375) about the dot before angle brackets.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to declare the keys of the objects in that array, and how to declare an array of objects with specific keys as a return type. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498975/document-collection-array-of-type-return-value-and-parameter-in-jsdoc/32139970#32139970) does.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I added such an example to my answer. I used this myself many times but it only makes sense if you know these details otherwise the more general object approach is better...

Comment: @Snekse, I know this is old, but you'd do {String[][]}

Comment: @RoboticRenaissance I haven't had to use it in a long time, so I wouldn't know any better to not use it.

Comment: Agree with Kenny806, but `Array.<>` is valid for non-Closure Compiler users.