# Why does JSDoc allow both Array<string> and Array.<string>, and is one better than the other?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

JSDoc appears to have 2 different but similar syntaxes for
parametrised types.  An example of the first syntax
is `Array.<MyClass>` (you can find that [here](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html)).  An example of the second is `Array<number>`
(you can find that [here](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-interface.html)).
Why are both syntaxes supported, and is one better than the other?

Comment: Why would you expect one to be better than the other?

Comment: @Li357: I'm guessing that one syntax is newer than the other and was introduced because it was considered to be better.

Answer (score 6):

There is no "better" or "worth" way to document your code. What you see is inconsistency in the documentation on JSDoc. They have backlog item to make it consistent: [Clean up examples of type applications](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc3.github.com/issues/156), which say the following:

> Type applications no longer need to include periods. For example, you can write `Array<number>` rather than `Array.<number>`. We should update all of our examples to use the more streamlined syntax.

As of documenting `Arrays` of objects there is already answer on SO: [How to specify an array of objects as a parameter or return value in JSDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611995/how-to-specify-an-array-of-objects-as-a-parameter-or-return-value-in-jsdoc).

Comment: The text you quoted makes it clear that it's better to omit the dot.  This is clearer still in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1375#issuecomment-312524767), which says that "`Promise<number>` is preferable" to `Promise.<number>`.  Anyway, you have led me to the answer to my question, so thank you.

Comment: @StarFlow Glad it helped you. Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)