# Jsdoc array with more than one different thing in array

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I want to do jsdoc with something like the following

```
/**
@param {string|number[]}
*/
```

In the above it's an array of numbers or a string, but I want an array of numbers and/or strings. I need this to work for other things like 2 different kinds of objects. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: [How to specify an array of objects as a parameter or return value in JSDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611995/how-to-specify-an-array-of-objects-as-a-parameter-or-return-value-in-jsdoc)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Closure Compiler, you can write:

`/** @param {!Array<number|string>} x */
function f(x) {}`

See this [example](https://closure-compiler-debugger.appspot.com/#input0%3D%252F**%2520%2540param%2520%257B!Array%253Cnumber%257Cstring%253E%257D%2520x%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520f(x)%2520%257B%257D%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257B!Array%253Cboolean%253E%257D%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520a%2520%253D%2520%255Btrue%255D%253B%250A%250Af(a)%253B%250A%26input1%26conformanceConfig%26externs%26refasterjs-template%26CHECK_TYPES%3Dtrue%26TRANSPILE%3Dtrue%26CLOSURE_PASS%3Dtrue%26PRESERVE_TYPE_ANNOTATIONS%3Dtrue%26PRETTY_PRINT%3Dtrue).