# How to document resolved values of JavaScript promises

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Given this code :

```
function asyncFoo() {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    doAsyncStuff(function(err, data) {
      if(err) reject(new Error(err));
      else fulfill(new Bar(data));
    });
  });
}
```

How can I document that `asyncFoo` will return a `Promise` that, when fulfilled will yield an instance of `Bar`, and when rejected will yield an instance of `Error`?

```
/**
 * @return << Here, what do I have to write? >>
 */
function asyncFoo() { ... }
```

Comment: > Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104411/how-to-specify-resolution-and-rejection-type-of-the-promise-in-jsdoc/46733261#46733261

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like you should do the following, based on [some other source code's comments](https://github.com/icholy/cesium/commit/90630eed257edd86006cd39ff9a404adf500e3c8).

```
/**
 * @return {Promise.<Bar>}
 */
```

[How JavaScript Promises are documented.](https://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/Promise.html)

[Similar question with a similar answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104411/how-to-specify-resolution-and-rejection-type-of-the-promise-in-jsdoc) Note the lack of a dot in that answer.

Comment: Is the dot recommended or not? The JSDoc docs are ironically not very good.

Comment: For a bit more information take also a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726521/828366

Comment: Both https://jsdoc.app/tags-returns and https://jsdoc.app/tags-async suggest `{Promise<Bar>}`

Answer (score 12):

I like to specify that it's an async function with `@async` and specify the fulfilled return with `@returns` and error with `@throws`

```
/**
 * @async
 * @returns {Bar}
 * @throws {Error}
 */
function asyncFoo() { ... }
```

Comment: Should be an accepted answer. Works like a charm.
Only by this way result is correctly recognized by IDE when return value is defined as Interface in the TypeScript file (just for neat autocomplete).

Comment: and yet, the fn doesn't return `{Bar}` nor does it throw `{Error}`

Comment: Nor is the function defined as `async function` [Use JSDoc: @async](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-async.html)

Comment: JSDoc's manual does not recommend this for Promises in general such as the OP's `asyncFoo`: only for functions defined with `async` keyword. _"The @async tag indicates that a function is asynchronous, meaning that it was declared using the syntax async function foo() {}. Do not use this tag for other types of asynchronous functions, such as functions that provide a callback."_ https://jsdoc.app/tags-async.html

Comment: This should be the way to document it. Arguable a function can be considered `async` if it can be invoked with the `await` keyword. The `@async` annotation is needed for functions not declared with the `async` keyword but do return a promise.

Comment: Documentation suggests this answer is incorrect https://jsdoc.app/tags-async — the included example shows `{Promise<string>}`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to declare what can be thrown, neither through `@` directives nor through the `Promise` generic parameters (see [Typescript Promise rejection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071115/typescript-promise-rejection-type)).

Per documentation at https://jsdoc.app/ your code should look like:

```js
/**
 * @returns {Promise<Bar>}
 */
function asyncFoo() {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    doAsyncStuff(function(err, data) {
      if(err) reject(new Error(err));
      else fulfill(new Bar(data));
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I personally prefer strict differentiation - declare final type from async function and Promise from a function that directly returns Promise.

```
/**
  Async JSON request
  @param {string} sql
  @returns {object}
*/
async function request(sql)
{
  return JSON.parse(await dbEngine.executeRequest(sql));
}

/**
  Async JSON request
  @param {string} sql
  @returns {Promise<string>}
*/
function request(sql)
{
  return dbEngine.executeRequest(sql);
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect though. Async functions always return a promise