# Why does the Promise generic type only declare the success resolution type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Say I have the following code:

```js
function fn(): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let randomBit = (Math.random() * 10) % 2 === 0;

    if (randomBit) {
      resolve("Resolve");
    } else {
      reject(0);
    }
  });
}
```

The above method, which returns a valid Promise, is correctly typed as `Promise<string>`. I understand that the internal type declares the type returned in the case of a successful resolution. But, what about the return of a rejection? In my example the rejection would resolve to `number`. Shouldn't, the return signature of `fn()` be something like

```
Promise<string, number>
```

?

Or, more generally, shouldn't a Promise declare the generic types for the two possible outcomes, like

```
Promise<TSuccess, TError>
```

?

I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: I think the accepted answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071115/typescript-promise-rejection-type answers your question. See the second paragraph there.

Comment: The function always returns a promise.  That promise may then resolve or reject.  So, there's no "return of a rejection".  There's always a return of a promise that, then sometime later, may resolve or reject.  The syntax is declaring that if it resolves, it will resolve with a string.  A rejection works like throwing an exception which can't be typed by TypeScript because that's a run-time occurence, not something the static code analysis of typescript can necessarily track.

Comment: It does @Ian! Excellent explanation. Considering deleting this question...

Comment: @seebiscuit don't worry about deleting it - leaving it closed as a duplicate is better for helping people discover the other answer in the future