# TypeScript: How to type react-query useMutation onError with generic?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics, react-query

Consider a custom `useSignUp` hook which `mutate()` function takes some fields (`name` and `email` in this example):

```
export default function App() {
  const name = "David";
  const email = "david@gmail.com";
  const signupMutation = useSignUp();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        signupMutation.mutate(
          { name, email },
          {
            onSuccess: (result) => {
              ...
            },
            onError: (result) => {
              // Wanted: result of type ErrorResult<"name" | "email">
            }
          }
        );
      }}
    >
      Sign Up
    </button>
  );
}
```

I'd like `onError`'s result to be of type `ErrorResponse<"name" | "email">` in this case. But, I get `ErrorResponse<string>`.

Why is that? How could I instruct TypeScript to infer the type to be specific based on the passed data (i.e. `"name" | "email"`, not `string`)?

Here is how I typed `useSignUp`:

```
type SuccessResponse = {
  userId: string;
};

type ErrorResponse<T> = {
  userId?: string;
  formErrors?: Array<{
    field: T;
    type: string;
  }>;
};

export const useSignUp = <T extends string>() => {
  return useMutation<SuccessResponse, ErrorResponse<T>, Record<T, string>>(
    (data) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Some logic here to either return a success or an error response
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
          resolve({
            userId: "1234"
          });
        } else {
          reject({
            formErrors: [
              {
                field: "email", // I want TypeScript to complain if it's neither "name" nor "email"
                type: "ALREADY_EXISTS"
              }
            ]
          });
        }
      });
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: About your `reject` signature, the param can't be changed. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071254/9449426) answer.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko could you please provide reproducible example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already declared a hook with a generic error field, if you don't provide the param, it defaults to a string:

```js
export const useSignUp = <T extends string>() => {
  return useMutation<SuccessResponse, ErrorResponse<T>, Record<T, string>>(...)
}
```

So make sure to override it:

```
type Field = 'name' | 'email';

// ...

useSignUp<Field>();
```

If you want to type the error based on the submitted values:

```
const mutatedValues = {
  name: "David",
  email: "david@gmail.com"
};
const signupMutation = useSignUp<keyof typeof mutatedValues>();
```

```
onError: (result) => {
  result.formErrors?.forEach((e) => {
    const { field } = e; // field is 'name' | 'email'
  });
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Is it possible to avoid providing the generic to `useSignUp` and let TypeScript to `infer` it somehow?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko In theory, I think Typescript can infer the params of the `onError` callback based on the `mutatedValues` by making the `mutate()` function from `react-query` aware of the key of the data, but the library doesn't support it. They only allow you to override `TData` or `TError` individually.

Comment: the types need to be defined on the useMutation call. You can't have useMutation infer it's types based on what you will then eventually pass to `mutate`. Either pass the generics explicitly as suggested here, or make a specific mutation that is tied to userName / email (no generics), or pass the fields directly to useMutation (if available) so that you can infer from it: `const signupMutation = useSignUp({ name, email });`. You can then call `.mutate()` without params and closure over what you've passed to useMutation. Then, inference should work.