# Typescript return multiple promise types

Tags: typescript

I have have some types like tihs

```
export interface Result<T> { data: T};
export type ErrorResult = Result<string>;
export type ErrorResponse = Promise<ErrorResult>;
export type SuccessResult = Result<any>;
export type SuccessResponse = Promise<SuccessResult>;
```

Why won't TS let me write a function like

```
export async function stuff(): ErrorResponse | SuccessResponse {}
```

It will only let me do

```
export async function stuff(): Promise<ErrorResult | SuccesResult> {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Promise rejection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071115/typescript-promise-rejection-type)

Comment: Not at all. I am not throwing anything. I wanted to declare that the function returns different promises. Just surprised I have to do it in the way described.

Comment: Looks like [ms/TS#6631](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6631) enforces the restriction that only native `Promise`s can be returned, and the return type annotation must be an instance of the native `Promise` **and nothing else**.  I don't know that it was ever intended to disallow [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of promises, but that is one of the effects, intended or otherwise. Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: More questions for context: do you *need* the function to be `async`?  You can still `await` it [even if it's not](https://tsplay.dev/wEB54N).  How are you implementing the function?  Are you *actually* returning a union of promises or are you actually returning a promise of unions but just want to *annotate* it as a union of promises?

Comment: Hmm, seems you've accepted the existing answer even though it does not actually answer the question as asked.  As far as I can tell, the answer is to point to [ms/TS#6631](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6631) and related GitHub issues.  Maybe you want to [edit] the question so that the accepted answer actually answers it?   Or maybe someone should edit the answer to include this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, a function declared as `async` *always* returns a `Promise`. That promise can be `await`-ed to retrieve a value of the internal type. ([Read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value))

E.g.

```js
async function getName() {
  // Example internals..
  return "Celine";
}

const theNamePromise = getName();
//    ^^ This is a Promise<string>

const theName = await getName();
//    this is a string ("Celine")
```

Edit:
More specific to your example:

(Note, I don't actually have a convincing answer here. But I did some tinkering and found some mildly interesting things. The below is a very short write-up of what I found, and [here is the example code I was playing with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0+mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS+ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCJQh4vS22+yQYS0e+iiqAAPDgAHygADecLqDHy3gAvgBuRQDsjW9qgGlkNhkCeCKc80DnqfTqmUTjMOc7vcHohHk-i88ERqZq+0NhECESBp2PU8b2gVBn13dZBzQQ9iHYWALEEQQIJoXl0OnMw8Gg194PfRDkP0ND9B-SkUF5ACkGA6ciJQ0iL0g6CYJ-fcxGOcwcS4WB6kaK5UHYRElR1ddqKAzNQM-M9J0g0AAB9QHo-R0IXRcN2CfCGE42BuPMPivCpITkgAJhE9cwK-MjfxQRTlNQ78bKXDTFG0k5dOSHiDIE4yAGZzLoQDaPvYYF0U8TaM4dhEGkb453U-UwFikUJAEYQfwyVB+CGR9hCdIcFAJepHwCUrgk8-SGi8fL0ICrCQsfMLr1kmcopiuKl0UEoSicQSTU67rBpXPN1wAWTqTAAjIFwkBE0AFwABgCABWUAAH5+QUKlg3XZbeC67rt0UFyKt4qrs1QdCzNE5qmJnBqRkUtrYrINSDp6nN8S8Rd3qG7hVzGiappmxA5o2vkttQHbQD236jpOrzzpqlr-Ju+rUAfJ8FNu29no6n7BoRUAlXG2JgZ4WadXm0AluWqmCaGj6+u+37GZKf6Rs2-Qof2tnQCOwaN3BaA-wZxneq+ga+e6jm1xh3m2Y0wXjuCIA))

It's important to note that `Promise<string> | Promise<number>` and `Promise<string | number>` are close, but not entirely equivalent as far as TypeScript is concerned.

To explain with an example, suppose we take your `Result<T>` type and used it similarly:

```
function getResult(): Result<string> | Result<number> {
    // This return statement yields a TS error
    return {
        data: Math.random() > 0.5 ? "test" : 5,
    };
}
```

If you plug this into TS, you'll get an error, because the value being returned is of type `{ data: string | number; }`, not `{ data: string; } | { data: number; }`.

That type *is* assignable to `Result<string | number>`

```
function getResult2(): Result<string | number> {
    // This is valid
    return {
        data: Math.random() ? "test" : 5,
    };
}
```

Now, this highlights a difference between how TS sees these types, but doesn't *necessarily* explain why the top-level type returned by an `async` can't be an intersection between two `Promise<T>` types. Afraid I don't have a thorough answer there.

Comment: Yeah.. I mean, I know what a promise and async/await is. My question is why TS does not let me return multiple Promise types.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Will update the answer.

Comment: Turns out, I actually don't have a convincing answer here, but discovered some interesting things along the way. Updated the answer what some additional info.