# How does the exception handling with promises in Typescript work?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
  static sendForm(form: Form): Promise<MyEntity> {
    return this.post(request, `path`);
  }
```

So this typescript Function return a Promise of type MyEntity . This is a concrete type.
The caller knows this post request will be return a MyEntity so everything is fine.

```
  static post(obj: Object, path: string): Promise<any> {
    return axios
      .post(`${serviceUrl}/${path}`, JSON.stringify(obj), defaultConfig)
      .then((response) => mapToCustomResponse(response))  
      .catch(async (error) => Promise.reject(Utils.catchError(error)));
  }
```

So the then(..) will return a promise of type MyEntity.
But in the case of an error it will go to the catch method and this will not return a MyEntity.
It will return a rejected promise of some other type , which in my case will be some error object.

So now what I don't understand.
The calling method expects a MyEntity object. But in case of error it will get something else, nameley an error object.

In the tests I have written it seems typescript is not complaining about it.
Shouldn't typescript say: Hey, the object is not of type MyEntity and give me an error ?

Comment: I don't get it, should `error` be of type `MyEntity`?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071115/typescript-promise-rejection-type) might help.

Comment: _"The calling method expects a MyEntity object"_... no, the calling method expects `Promise<MyEntity>` which can either resolve with `MyEntity` or reject. The link provided by @c0m1t should shed some light on rejection / error typing

Comment: Have you tried not using `any`

Comment: Consider this expression... `const p: Promise<MyEntity> = Promise.reject("error")`. This is valid Typescript because a rejected promise can adhere to any generic promise type. The rejection value itself is untyped (**always** being of type `any` as explained in the duplicate)

Comment: FYI Axios is able to strongly type the response so you can avoid `Promise<any>`. Also, you appear to be unnecessarily stringifying your request payload and are probably passing in redundant headers in `defaultConfig`