# How to describe the Promise rejection for a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

In Typescript, is there a way to describe the `reject()` call from a Promise, for the functions return type?

For example, I have a function, `validate()` that takes some JSON and checks it's valid. If it is, a `resolve()` is returned. Otherwise, a `reject()` is returned, with a simply object, containing the error(s).

Is there a way to describe the `Promise<>` return type, so that I know it can potentially fail and return the `reject()`?

A bit like PHP @throws annotation, so the IDE can help to indicate that the exception hasn't been handled.

This is not the same as [Typescript Promise rejection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071115/typescript-promise-rejection-type), as I am wanting to set the functions return type to describe that the function can result in a promise rejection being thrown (with the type of data inside them as a bonus)

Comment: what kind of error or object does the `validate()` function return? Can you define its rejection structure?

Comment: @jkalandarov the `reject()` return inside `validate()` returns an object, `{errors: validationErrors}` where `validationErrors` is an array of JS Error objects.

Comment: How exactly isn't it the same as the linked duplicate? Of course a promise *can* be rejected, that's expected. You want to annotate what type the rejection result will have. That's exactly what the duplicate is about. If it's not, clarify what's wrong about my above description.

Comment: "*This is not the same as Typescript Promise rejection type*" - it is **exactly** the same. There is no way to signal this in the type signature. Every promise can be rejected, and with `any` kind of value.